# Generate multiple PDF for a single report in COGNOS

Tags: cognos-bi, cognos-10

I need to use COGNOS 10 to generate a report that will have about 300 pages. I want each page saved as a separate pdf file. Is there a way to automagically do this or do I need to run the report 300 times manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can try bursting.  Assuming that each page breaks on a specific grouping, you could set up a page-set that groups on the grouping you intend to page-break and then have it burst to that same grouping.  You should get a PDF file for each of the groups.  Therefore, if there are 300 groupings, 300 page-breaks, and 300 burst groupings then the net result will be 300 separate PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to do this from within Cognos with a single report. You can only have one output file per individual report run. There shouldn't be a need for separate outputs from a single report, perhaps you can provide your scenario and maybe the community can find alternatives.

The best workaround I can think of would be to make 300 separate reports and run them as a job.